While Levy's not a GM, is $\mathbb{G}_m$ a Levi?
Or put it another way, let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over a field $k$. Is $G$ a parabolic of itself? The identity morphism is of course projective and hence proper, but I'm wondering if there's a convention issue here.

Yes, $G$ is considered as a Levi of itself.

What do mean by "Levy" (with a "y") and by "GM" ?

@AlexYoucis Ok thanks. Just making sure, only for reductive $G$ right?

@PaulBroussous "Levy" is a celebrity chess player, and "GM" Is referring to the fact he is currently trying to become a grandmaster.

So it seems like it's true: Levy's not a GM (yet), but $\mathbb{G}_m$ is a Levi.
